# Samba - Error while copying , invalid argument

Tags: 14.04, samba

I have installed samba on Ubuntu 14.04, but other users are not able to copy files from my shared folder.

This is my situation:

> **Error while copying "index.html".**
>
> There was an error copying the file into smb://192.168.11.108/www.
>
> ↓ Show more details
>
> Invalid argument

[image]

And my smb.conf settings are:

```
[html]
    comment = HTML
    path = /var/www/html
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes
```

What is the problem here and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Looks like the share is read only for that user, also looks like the file is copied to, and not from the share.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a share for your web folder.  For security, the files are usually only writable by the owner.  The default group and owner is `www-data`.

You will have to change the folder's permission to either allow anyone in the world to write to it, or change the permission so that the group can write to it and add the samba userID to the `www-data` group.

The world writable is very insecure, unless the share is a public access where you want the world to be able to make changes to the folder (the world as in anyone with login access to your system).  The latter (adding the samba account to the `www-data` group is more secure if the account would only be shared with trusted users.

There are other alternatives such as changing the group and owner of folder to a different `user/group` such as the userID given to the samba account of the logged in user.